# How do I download picture from website using wget

Tags: web, wget

Hi I want to download all images from a site but only certain ones i was using.

`wget -r --directory-prefix=/savelocation -A .jpg www.example.com/`

but that just ends up trying to download the entire site and not sure why.

I should probably mention I have only just started using wget because I was told it was quick and easy.

I want to download all the pictures from http://wall.alphacoders.com/ under the category "Fantasy" and only that category.

http://wall.alphacoders.com/by_category.php?id=11&name=Fantasy+Wallpapers

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

i would be careful, they state in their terms:

> "Attempt to access or search the Services, User Content or Alpha
> Coders Content through the use of any engine, software, tool, agent,
> device or mechanism (including automated scripts, spiders, robots,
> crawlers, data mining tools or the like) other than the software
> and/or search agents provided by Alpha Coders or other generally
> available third party web browsers;
>
> Attempt to scrape or download User
> Content or Alpha Coders Content from the Services, or otherwise use,
> upload content to, or create new links, reposts, or referrals in the
> Service through the stated methods above;"